# Java BLS signature aggregation

Tags: java, algorithm, cryptography, elliptic-curve

Definition: BLS signature aggregation is taking **n** signatures of **n** distinct messages and aggregate them into one short signature that has the same length range as the rest of the signatures. The combined short signature, along with the original messages and public keys, should convince the verifier that each message was signed by the owner of the public key. More details about it can be found in [this](https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/pubs/papers/aggreg.pdf) paper.

I have successfully [implemented](https://github.com/gazman-sdk/BLS_signature_aggregation/blob/master/src/test/java/com/gazman/bls/BlsSignaturesTest.java) BLS signature aggregation on top of [JPBC](http://gas.dia.unisa.it/projects/jpbc/#.WnoGLqinGCo) library. But the result got very bad performance, and I am not able to wrap it with the native API for some reason...

Ther for I want to switch to [IAIK-JCE](https://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/), they offer 256-bit implementation of 
type 3 BN(Barreto Naehrig) Elliptic Curve.

But their implementation requires more math knowledge than I can offer. I am stuck on the very first step of generating the private key.

Can you help me please build a simple example to sign and verify a single message?

Here is a code example of what I got from **IAIK-JCE** so far:

```
   /**
     * Contains some basic pairing examples, including the usage of Type-2 and
     * Type-3 curves and hashing onto curves (onto curve 1 for Type-2 and onto
     * curve 1 and 2 for Type-3 pairings). Note that hashing to curve 2 is not
     * possible in case of Type-2 pairings.
     *
     * @param size the size of the curve to be used
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     */
    private static void run(final int size) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        // create Type-3 pairing
        final Pairing pairing3 = AtePairingOverBarretoNaehrigCurveFactory
                .getPairing(PairingTypes.TYPE_3, size);

        EllipticCurve g1 = pairing3.getGroup1();
        EllipticCurve g2 = pairing3.getGroup2();
        GenericField target = pairing3.getTargetGroup();


        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println("Type-3 pairing:");
        System.out.println("G1: " + g1);
        System.out.println("G2: " + g2);
        System.out.println("target group: " + target);

        // obtain generators of the two curves
        ECPoint g1Generator = g1.getGenerator();
        ECPoint g2Generator = g2.getGenerator();

        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println("p = " + g1Generator);
        System.out.println("q = " + g2Generator);

        // compute pairing of p and q
        GenericFieldElement t = pairing3.pair(g1Generator, g2Generator);

        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println("e(p,q) = " + t);

        // hash onto curve 1
        final ECPoint p2 = g1.hashToPoint(iaik.utils.Util.toByteArray("Test hashing onto curve 1"));


        // get scalars
        final SecureRandom random = SecurityStrength
                .getSecureRandom(SecurityStrength.getSecurityStrength(g1.getField().getFieldSize()));
        BigInteger k1 = new BigInteger(size - 1, random);
        BigInteger k2 = new BigInteger(size - 1, random);

        // multiply points from curve 2 with scalars
        ECPoint r = g2Generator.clone().multiplyPoint(k1);
        ECPoint s = g2Generator.clone().multiplyPoint(k2);

        System.out.println("r: " + r);
        System.out.println("s: " + s);


        // compute pairing of p2 and r, and p2 and s
        GenericFieldElement[] ts = pairing3.pair(p2, new ECPoint[]{r, s});

        System.out.println("e(p2,r) = " + ts[0]);
        System.out.println("e(p2,s) = " + ts[1]);

        // hash onto curve 2
        final ECPoint q2 = g2.hashToPoint(iaik.utils.Util.toByteArray("Test hashing onto curve 2"));

        // multiply points from curve 1 with scalars
        r = g1Generator.clone().multiplyPoint(k1);
        s = g1Generator.clone().multiplyPoint(k2);

        // compute pairing of q2 and r, and q2 and s
        ts = pairing3.pair(new ECPoint[]{r, s}, q2);

        System.out.println("e(r,q2) = " + ts[0]);
        System.out.println("e(s,q2) = " + ts[1]);

        System.out.println("---");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean run() {
        System.out.println("IAIK Pairing Demo");
        System.out.println();

        try {
            run(256);
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());

            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        new Main().run();
    }
```

And it outputs:

```
---
Type-3 pairing:
G1: ext. Jacobian E/F_ba139ec2401edc28fb605c6b53e289b51311aca0d477df46feee89b1622c349b w. a=00000000, b=00000003
G2: ext. Jacobian E/F_ba139ec2401edc28fb605c6b53e289b51311aca0d477df46feee89b1622c349b/(X^2-ba139ec2401edc28fb605c6b53e289b51311aca0d477df46feee89b1622c349a) w. a=00000000 + 00000000i, b=00000003 + 00000003i
target group: (F_ba139ec2401edc28fb605c6b53e289b51311aca0d477df46feee89b1622c349b/(X^2-ba139ec2401edc28fb605c6b53e289b51311aca0d477df46feee89b1622c349a))/(X^6-(00000001 + 00000001i))
---
p = (00000001 : ba139ec2401edc28fb605c6b53e289b51311aca0d477df46feee89b1622c3499 : 00000001 : 00000001)
q = (699235e63bd94d51548c2e1d57dd658d238fd96fe418721c59172a4eb324274c + 0f3516436dbce492a68ebb406bc515ab8ebd2925caf01c711e75c422e6c8aca3i : 88357041e9bd66d654703ddbee1b0de7a9c0f6a430791e083176a5610efef314 + 737ce191f291c8845d5ca6cc8a76f0d20f31fd3b444e88984e1b267846268d8ai : 00000001 + 00000000i : 00000001 + 00000000i)
---
e(p,q) = (a94dd52af16ac4c868f6a65e8afbd7b7da5ac83b6bf3dc56006a02cb2593cd0c + 7bd8e09b5b3a3848d37eab855ff7b36d1bc4d6585868faf39af11e9e05a1d2aai, 60f12ec3f44243e53f9439a119838b7d5705ccbf6a2bbca5adeddc386f17f586 + 5f7cab2ac94c95ecb2e88d6bb3e65d81a0116ca60fdb4f0f3eb2614f149e1c9ai, 2983e255eec9d20f9f898506358c5f69ecffc8d936c68f879fe771e0335d87d4 + 905a0fcee353d979c5ab5eccd43e475eaf36dd4f4caa92b5f0d48c9a974be3dai, 3953c0b4af9af99855b6d2d15c0f5f2db3abee65ca116d272a5fe18c78a2cc1f + 0d8a8da7526ae1d1982a535aa1cd95a076b1811673cae0b2170e37d2ed812c33i, 996d381cba84679590b2a0c32b68e48a99a376ef3a8b85008c0ad29d015da991 + 1138dd84e4751228c237dec20b72b8068f64e629ba2c97ca0e1eb3a2aa07849ei, 702e0ff820b114eb8dc3b9e97300c6f990ba3dc763cb5685cfdc53182991d1db + 5c0d866b8a0d1a0fe00b0daa3b4f2240a9eb4117fcf7192096003f3344f1c8f3i)
r: (521e690d616b00bf994f0827ed59263320f973f6835166c3f607765ff49fb660 + 132f56183169a3f320c9bdc8b49e0ae86e75c7fc1d89de0ba986600865dc27cdi : 1cc33a0c3acda1614c43dc33d73c25c91513165a1132e57c97d3098c5ced1007 + 06161ead9e5c8e2ea35283528901f1114b6206afc114d9f2e88883bf8fdb6661i : 1d43f333046c2017d6c603e485437ee765f198dca362edb8262e9e44e5cf99c7 + b3496dcf8c0c376c65b3ee53cdb835c6d14920e26f6ac2c32e9d4c130046f14ai : 2b3d51a144d7c9cf8a11c6e778ab1f8937382bee36a750b83bc91e5dc018a5ed + 3f14d2c593f26bfec90c4f3d6fd8e7b27e43ba534ffd1febf258dd788847fb4ei)
e(p2,r) = (1e48382aecd4ea0a6eed04ce592f06791fab0dcd027c00766f98137a71d606e5 + 04e5e74366d03bd9a54499a3323b2e7b72eeb99f5ee8fe46a18395f634b6224ci, 24de58759cf1377d5830c830d1d0902cc66c1c3f1361aa1a4507266f98e1ec21 + 661afc8e156c2e39f426213fdab207302257f0e5960a980567dfa9a11b45f0dei, b544aa91abf6b3892fbc40593a1d464475b9b69be7b2967515aeb3f2c0907369 + aee0c0ee0d6c7bac2abce6472b81e9c8b8f071da26ebbbc2d286f93083b40899i, 8fc0ffa9c2cfbe7e282223808036887a20ce5438569b07d34950b873381d0727 + b1bd58a6cb88de43970d4d970c8c15dc14892c1f501d400afc153848fe136f97i, 84451776a746ac0553eef99fec947d9893193fd0f7c35c7a2a8b202e42f2ac7b + 34a481a6f50337a35189ced27e7f496951d4ff142c5385f27b8138686dcb7043i, ae24a6c1b9da20a41b8792f4ac4d99839d099037a59310e59060a7d169f7502f + 30bae55cda364da63fe6bd193ac0301592457570b1524fbcab7f2b596edf49bei)
e(p2,s) = (5a9fd1aafedfb6a596b3e2781ed2e97056e06fb0f09357b69af4aa76aa8ff1ed + 88259021e86c2118933c50285f20ce74b7b0cedbd7197e1a533a116ba18cd9f1i, 9e4faf20f6782d34a7e25ebffbbe272774e11facf737165f299eb6a26969e9e3 + 287f56a8bf324f6f56a82e2dda966f2184420f26aed784bfcb38cde9a2407405i, 14a30d4b1d971f7c1a7cc61f56ee44eacf6ba9e99c370ef593f68717cffa0493 + 6d208db7ab26560b0f2179cf7c824d4935fa3a07be7f4169f3e6c59b37a5de0ai, 12e704b8a0f97a34c4b0b870b8d50d8bb37aef5412581df7c5ed260c6d82c349 + 1bfe6d1d4baaf16cd3b5ee733d4e614c5cc19dca1cf3cec70e01e240768f79d3i, a894c1f62057620313de3c26470ce44c6d510fc850950b6e2c7478cb1d7dd3f3 + 2911de4f9dd95e2b7896b903c19e6d630d627853035239f187af3d7596e4cc4fi, 4b64d86c73ae1ea37780c187aed4e35057e007653d4d61ab34c14d1227686cc3 + 9e9200baea012a0c0d1fe914360f5a4bbfdbd032e5607ac7dc3177950aa18a58i)
e(r,q2) = (6f8cf3a0658e883bc366107dca53b0d76b0f6f6f7ef74cb4e61b2aa8ab601e8b + 35b9be4155c4434ede6bde0672c39ec0c4f462ee8c27a06415fd18a53ccaf5cei, 4b1b8eb429cb3a71b7e27b017a740ae4f7b6359e5c044f4cd6c2c588834c0169 + 2867122dd3f54bab64bcec5df5b4300c6ea7fcc6f4969d9e5935cdaacaee817di, 17bc103e92added726cd25c7141f707210212036e5252ad7cd24060fc254df6a + 010d499c20ade19e48e410460b1932dc112fd7953da08b5cfd89b53a99f2244bi, 18358eb20e9efb4aa4baef1b64f0fa2df2e17e7b05cfc4d7e5d9eeed3b784076 + 5f9b23465fd8cf3f5daf81bde23e45972e2c6376c066cccb7877617ebf4d7483i, 61d4ff939fcfb7de27becd5bdf311a98593fa2ca1ab34eeb369882cb821ea108 + 0a093f1713d049952218cd0852e2f3e023bb7ee8665c56cce69b6bc3c474e131i, afadf9f17edda1bd4e01cdae14bc0305baf40394da29edf0841b2e8633d12513 + 59845d3902056aa215bb12ccfdefe5060e42e2e8f6a614d3150b8ee185525f29i)
e(s,q2) = (57dcf60ee4369e9858d1dd467f5ec891e461fea0c94cb6bd9bc82aed91d907fb + 91f2801c495392b484f9d21d7181b9a03dfd4b087160ec4d070388f258f095e1i, 8b9241d6475e23fd2a2bd234fd8cbfba4063693d40e0b38640ea817cb8b79712 + 584db86871f773a37e3772b1ecf6f2df98da96cacafcd9a6857fae64789e6ea6i, 4d21aef28f52b15504f2acff346112f3f62301631acc2896c91cb73a0f2ecf3f + 2a069b2403057f081e40d88882df4f69b09360116566dde6635eba4be128a5a9i, 5005c52502d0e10132c013566f529ab1756bf6484dbc95c005ac819f0efd51b0 + 805cad8dd3d4d609c4ba20a774e2e5fda8ff44f5dd306538203c7dbca3453ebei, 8d77f775f53b4b5e2bd3c841237841849c22c6d13b3920ce24489fa5f453eba9 + a162fe065ebf64fb4e126cab783e4a925043442f780c0366d179a043e279beb6i, 8c26c60b80127e0544fea0ac66934c00fc909dadab8d1f22f3ee7f0db037dd2b + abccff963161c1947b9d470cae596506a3f1ae84f660e1861410e095a5d2f9efi)
---
```